# Why is one of these classes not inheriting from the interface I made?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I'm trying to get a handle on inheritance and interfaces, and I've got two working files:

```
interface Speaker{

  public String nameCalled();
  public void describeSelf(String s);
  public double randomIt(String s);
}
```

import java.util.Random;

```
public class testSample implements Speaker{


  public String name1;
  public String occ;

  public testSample(String name1, String occ){
    this.name1 = name1;
    this.occ = occ;
  }


  public String nameCalled(){
    return "My name is " + name1 + ".";
  }

  public void describeSelf(String s){
    System.out.println("I, " + name1 + ", am a " + occ + ".");
  }

  public double randomIt(String s){
    return Math.random() * s.length();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    testSample t = new testSample("John","student");
    System.out.println(t.nameCalled());
    System.out.println(t.randomIt("money"));
  }

}
```

but then, with this:

```
public class testSample2 extends testSample implements Speaker{

  String name;

  public String nameCalled(){};
  public void describeSelf(String s){
    System.out.println("They call me " + name + ".");
  }
  public double randomIt(String s){
    return Math.random() * s.length();
  }

}
```

my compiler says "1 error found:
File: C:\Users\user\Desktop\testSample2.java  [line: 1]
Error: constructor testSample in class testSample cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

I want     testSample2 to inherit the variables from testSample but with different outputs. Also, what's the point of interfaces, if on testSample, I can just comment out "implements Speaker" and testSample still works.

Comment: Hint: please read about java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase, always. And: dont call something "testClass" ... that says **nothing** about the intended usage. At least call it it BaseTestClass and then ExtendingTestClass or something alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base class has **one** constructor:

```
public testSample(String name1, String occ){
```

Thing is: a child class **must** always call **one** constructor from its super class. Even when you dont write down an explicit constructor, the compiler will add the default no-argument taking constructor.

Thus: the compiler tries to add that default ctor to the child class. And as said, that constructor must call some super constructor. **But**: there is no default constructor in your super class.

Long story short: you need something like:

```
public testSample2(String name1, String occ){
  super(name1, occ)
```

for example.

Think about it: inheritance is about an **IS A** relationship. A testSample2 **is** a testSample, too. And "testSample" needs those two parameters to be instantiated. So testSample2 must provide those two arguments *somehow* upon creation.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `testSample2` in inheriting `testSample`

so what you need to do is: in the constructor of `testSample2`  you have to call the **constructor of the parent class** by invoking `super(string, string)`